# Why this set is closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers, natural-numbers

I've read somewhere that the set $K=\{(\frac{1}{n}, n):n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and I have no idea how to prove this. Can someone help?

Comment: First, remind yourself and remind us what your definition is of "*closed.*"  Probably having something to do with balls of some particular radius?  Now, recall that such balls encircle a region that not only extends horizontally around a point *but vertically too* as well as at an angle.

Comment: This all being said... the final result and explanation will depend heavily upon exactly how "*closed*" is being defined, which is equivalent to asking you the question "*Under what 'topology' are you considering this?*"  In certain topologies, this might have actually been open.

Comment: A common definition of "set A is closed" is "A contains all of its limit points".  So what are the limit points of this set?  (it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$K$ has no limit point, because distance of every distinct two members of $K$ is strictly greater than $1$. Hence the members of $K$ do not cluster anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x,y)\notin K$.

- If $y<1$, then the open ball around $(x,y)$ of radius $r=1-y$ is disjoint from $K$
- If $y\ge 1$ and $y\notin \Bbb N$, then the open ball of radius $r=\min\{y-\lfloor y\rfloor, \lceil y\rceil -y\}$ is disjoint form $K$
- If $y\in \Bbb N$, this means $x\ne \frac1y$ and this time we can take $r=\min\{|x-\frac1y|, 1\}$.